# GUI Cross Threading issue/Looking for a good example of a WinForm TextBox Autocomplete as you type from database

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking fr a good example of a WinForm Autocomplete textbox that goes to the database for a list of matching items much like Google's AutoSuggest search text box does.

For example, if the user types really fast we need not submit one database search for each keystoke, however, after retriving results, if the user has queued up additional keystokes that have not been searched, do another search.

Update:

For example,

I've never done multi -thread before in a WinForm app but I thought I would start up a new thread every time the contents of the Search Text box changed and I would query the database for matches. If the textbox changed by the time I got the results back, I would disregard the query results.

However, I am getting this error:

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created o
```

Here's my code:

```
 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Thread newThread = new Thread(BeginSourceThread);
            newThread.Start(txtSearch.Text);
        }

        private void BeginSourceThread(object value)
        {

            string searchText = (string)value;

            AutoCompleteStringCollection autoCompleteItems = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            DataSet ds = MetaData.GetMatchingDatabaseObjects(txtSearch.Text, sqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
            DataTable dtbObjects = ds.Tables[0];

            if (txtSearch.Text != searchText)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in dtbObjects.Rows)
            {
                autoCompleteItems.Add(row["ObjectName"].ToString());
            }

            txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteItems;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done Returning " + autoCompleteItems.Count.ToString() + " items.");

      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it with the Key_Down event refreshing the results:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243368/AutoComplete-Textbox

Comment: This also doesn't do what Google does as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteItems` line inside an [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx) call to ensure that you are modifying the GUI only inside the main UI thread:

```
Action<AutoCompleteStringCollection> action = items => txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = items;
Invoke(action, autoCompleteItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

If relevant, autosuggest in the quintessential example of [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx):

- [Hands-on-Lab](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/D/C5D669F9-01DF-4FAF-BBA9-29C096C462DB/Rx%20HOL%20.NET.pdf) (see exercise 5)
- [DevCamp 2010 Keynote](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/codefest/DC2010T0100-Keynote-Rx-curing-your-asynchronous-programming-blues) (autosuggest is one of the live demos)